# Making two painted objects move in Java

Tags: java

I am hoping that you can help me. I have written two classes that have the purpose of making two alien faces move within a frame. The movements will be based upon user input. My program runs, but the movement of the faces won't occur. I am not sure if something is wrong with my translation of the alien faces' x and y coordinates. My questions are this:

Am I implementing translate incorrectly and how can I fix it?

The two classes are below. Thank you for your time and for your help!

```js
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Scanner;


/**
 * This program will print two alien faces in a frame and do one of several actions
 * based on user input.
 * @author ryanhabershaw
 *
 */

 public class FaceTester
 {
  /**
   * This is the main method of the program. No return.
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {  
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter q to terminate program. ");
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Enter d to make the faces move diagonally. ");
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Enter h to make the faces move horizontally. ");
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Enter v to make the faces move vertically. ");
   System.out.println();
   
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   frame.setSize(500, 500);
   frame.setTitle("Two Alien Faces");
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   FaceComponents component = new FaceComponents();
   
   
   
   int control = 5;
   while(control < 6)
   {
    System.out.println("Please enter an input: ");
    System.out.println();
    String user = in.next();
    if(user.equals("q") || (user.equals("Q"))) 
    {
     control++;
     System.out.println("Thanks for playing! The program has now terminated.");
    }
    else if(user.equals("d") || (user.equals("D")))
    {
     frame.add(component);
     FaceComponents.translate(100,200);
     
     frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    else if(user.equals("v") || (user.equals("V")))
    {
     frame.add(component);
     FaceComponents.translate(0,100);
     
     frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    else if(user.equals("h") || (user.equals("H")))
    {
     frame.add(component);
     FaceComponents.translate(100,0);
     
     frame.setVisible(true);
    }
   }
   
   in.close();
  }
 }
```

```js
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class FaceComponents extends JComponent
{  
 /**
  * This is the method where both of the alien faces and 
  * their features are created. No return.
  * @param g
  */
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
 {  
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

  
  Ellipse2D.Double head = new Ellipse2D.Double(5, 10, 100, 150);
  g2.draw(head);

  g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
     Rectangle eye = new Rectangle(25, 70, 15, 15);
     g2.fill(eye);
     eye.translate(50, 0);
     g2.fill(eye);


     Line2D.Double mouth = new Line2D.Double(30, 110, 80, 110);
     g2.setColor(Color.RED);
     g2.draw(mouth);

     //Separation between the heads for organization purposes.

     g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
     g2.drawString("Greetings Earthling", 5, 175);
     
     Ellipse2D.Double secondHead = new Ellipse2D.Double(150, 10, 100, 150);
  g2.draw(secondHead);

  g2.setColor(Color.RED);
     Rectangle secondEye = new Rectangle(165, 70, 15, 15);
     g2.fill(secondEye);
     secondEye.translate(50, 0);
     g2.fill(secondEye);


     Line2D.Double secondMouth = new Line2D.Double(225, 110, 175, 110);
     g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
     g2.draw(secondMouth);
     
     g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
     g2.drawString("Take us to your leader", 150, 175);
   }

 public static void translate(int i, int j) 
 {
  
 }

 
 }
```

Comment: After a quick look, I can't see any code for redrawing after each "frame".

Comment: @SteveSmith So you think that within the while loop, for each if statement, I should open another frame?

Comment: You do not have any implementation in translate

Comment: @Taquinas7, you could try adding `component.repaint()` inside the loop.

Comment: @SteveSmith I imagine that I will need the Graphics2D library imported into my FaceTester class to do that, right?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  Just add the line  `component.repaint()` or `component.invalidate()` (IIRC).

Comment: @SteveSmith It seems that that doesn't work.

Comment: @Sanjeev What do you mean? Doesn't the Graphics2D library have translate implementation within it?

Comment: As@Sanjeev says, your `translate` method is empty.  And it's static.  And why are you re-adding component after each time the user enters something?

Comment: @SteveSmith I was re-adding component in an attempt to get the faces to translate properly, but I have since deleted that from my code. I think I am still confused on how to write a translate method.

Comment: Yes `Graphics2D` has a translate method but you are specifically calling `FaceComponents` `translate` method which extends `JComponent` not `Graphics2D`

Comment: @Sanjeev So how do I go about writing my own translate method then?

Comment: @Taquinas7 you need to write code in your translate method which will update TOP LEFT co-ordinates of your faces